# How to use IpyWidget value within Databrick SQL notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, databricks

I'm a beginner in DataBrick and I'm trying to create a notebook which has a SQL query.  I want to utilize two input parameters for my query, one is a simple text and the other is date time.

From researching I learned about SQL widget for the Text input but I have to use the new IpyWdiget DatePicker for the date value.

- How would I get this date widget to show up like the Text widget.
- How can I use the date widget input value in my SQL script.

My attempt so far:

[image]